# Python: Removing entries from ordered list, that are not in unordered list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists:

```
ordered = ['salat', 'baguette', 'burger', 'pizza']
unordered = ['pizza', 'burger']
```

Now I want to remove all entries from the ordered list, that are not in the unordered list while preserving the ordering.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you care about preserving the order of ordered?

Comment: Yes, I need the ordering

Comment: can you give example sizes of unordered and ordered and how big the overlap is. Are there possibly also other items in unordered?

Comment: The lists are under 20 items and overlap by around 80%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ordered = [item for item in ordered if item in unordered]
```

This method creates a new list based on the old ones using Python's list comprehension.

For large amounts of data, turning the *unordered* list into a set first, as people suggested in comments, makes a huge difference in performance, e.g.:

```
unordered = set(unordered)
```

---

#### Benchmark!

> *ordered*: 5000 items, *unordered*: 1000 items
> 0.09561s without set
> 0.00042s with set

For 10/2 items the time is almost the same, so it's good to always use a set, no matter what the data size is.

Comment: This is probably what I'd do, although if the lists were long I'd probably make a set version of unordered to speed up membership testing.

Comment: +1 This is the most idiomatic solution. I wouldn't try to speed it up, either, unless performance became a concern.

Comment: Would make sense to turn `unordered` into a `set` to improve the runtime efficiency

Comment: @DSM: Ah! Sorry, must have been a browser cache/refresh issue. Although, why would it be faster to use a list (and not a set) for smaller data sets? Is the hash function really that time expensive or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:  In the case of 4 and 2 (for which I get timeit results of 0.473s without a set to 0.696 with) the set construction overhead is simply too large.  Of course, in this trivial case it takes so little time anyway there's little reason to worry about performance at all..

Answer (score 2):

Better use a set for testing membership, like this:

```
ordered = ['salat', 'baguette', 'burger', 'pizza']
unordered = ['pizza', 'burger']

unord = set(unordered)
ordered = [e for e in ordered if e in unord]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ordered = list(filter(lambda x: x not in unordered, ordered))
```

The `list` function is unnecessary if using Python < 3.

Comment: I have to say, this is quite ugly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't think of list comprehensions until I saw your answer.